# How to use 'EnumOrdinalTypeHandler' with mybatis's typeHandler in Spring's xml?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, enums, mybatis

I am using mybatis with spring.
I want to store Enum type with int value(which called 'ordinal') in mysql.There is a simple way in mybatis:

```
<!-- mybatis-config.xml -->
<typeHandlers>
<typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"     javaType="com.stackoverflow.MyEnumType"/>
</typeHandlers>
```

So when excute select or insert sql,the auto-mapper will automatically use EnumOrdinalTypeHandler.

My question is:

1:How to use this in Spring's context.xml like this or any other way:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="typeHandlers">
     ...
    </property>
</bean>
```

2:How can I configure for all enum types with less code such as `'component-scan'` or `'MapperScannerConfigurer'`,no need to list every enum type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Set your `mybatis-config.xml` location via:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="configLocation" value="mybatis-config.xml" />
</bean>
```

2.If you using java config, try using a loop:

```
TypeHandlerRegistry typeHandlerRegistry = sqlSessionFactory.getObject().getConfiguration().getTypeHandlerRegistry();
for (Class<?> cls: EnumClassArrays) {
    typeHandlerRegistry.register(cls, new EnumOrdinalTypeHandler<>(cls))
}
```